# Getting the fields attached to a bundle of an entity in Drupal

Tags: php, drupal

I don't want to get any information from the fields, all I want to get are the field machine names attached to a specific bundle (instance of an entity).

I'm looking into entityfieldquery, entity_load, and entity_get_info, and and I'm leaning towards entity_get_info, but now I'm reading that use is deprecated.

```
function multi_reg_bundle_select() {


$query = entity_get_info('registration');


}
```

How do I get information from the attached bundle? ('registration['bundlename']')? Ultimately I just want to get the fields attached to a particular bundle. Preferably in an array of strings.

Answer (score 3):

You can find the answer at https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14352/listing-entity-fields

Short answer: use

```
$fields = field_info_instances();
```

to get all info about all entity types and bundles, or use

```
$fields = field_info_instances('node', 'article');
```

to get only the fields of the node type "article".

Answer (score 3):

The easiest way to get only the field machine names attached to a specific bundle would be this:

```
$field_names = array_keys(field_info_instances('node', 'article'));
```

Using the function already mentioned; a disadvantage of [field_info_instances()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_instances/7) in some circumstances is that it does not provide the field *type*.  The lightest weight function for that in Drupal 7 is [field_info_field_map()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field_map/7).  It can be put in a helper function like this:

```
/**
 * Helper function to return all fields of one type on one bundle.
 */
function fields_by_type_by_bundle($entity_type, $bundle, $type) {
  $chosen_fields = array();
  $fields = field_info_field_map();
  foreach ($fields as $field => $info) {
    if ($info['type'] == $type &&
        in_array($entity_type, array_keys($info['bundles'])) &&
        in_array($bundle, $info['bundles'][$entity_type]))
    {
      $chosen_fields[$field] = $field;
    }
  }
  return $chosen_fields;
}
```

And use it like so, to get all taxonomy fields on the article content type:

```
$fields = fields_by_type_by_bundle('node', 'article', 'taxonomy_term_reference');
```

Note that field_info_field_map() gives only the machine name (as the original poster requested), but you'd have to load the field object with [field_info_field()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_field/7) to get the field label (human-readable name).

Answer (score 0):

I believe that field_info_bundles() may be what I am looking for. I'll let people know when I've tested it (but still, if you have suggestions, I'm happy to hear them!)

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.info.inc/function/field_info_bundles/7

Comment: This does not appear to be the solution.

Comment: Possibly this: $fields = array();

$fields_info = field_info_instances('registration', $bundle_name);
foreach ($fields_info as $field_name => $value) {
$fields[] = $field_name;

return $fields;

}